# How to diagnose Mercedes E320 ESP warning?

Tags: mercedes-benz, cel, obd, traction-control

My 2007 Mercedes W211 E320 CDI bottomed out on a deeply rutted road this past weekend, now I'm getting an ESP (traction control) inoperative warning on the dash.

I've had a look underneath and there's no obvious faults besides a big long scratch mark and mud on the bottom of the plastic covers. Torque Pro is showing some codes:

- P0132: O2 Sensor Circuit High Voltage. This is self-explanatory, but may not be related to the damage. I'm not getting a check engine light
- U1408: Torque doesn't say what this is, the web conflicts, either saying it's ABS related or emissions related. I'm going to work on the assumption that it's traction control related, more detail would be welcome

I'm going to pull the covers off and have a look, but I'm hoping to find out if there's a commonality I don't know about that may help me figure out the problem, or if there's a better way to get details about the code.